# using web.Application with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.5, aiohttp

I am trying to understand how to make this [example](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/web_srv.py) take an `aiohttp.web.Application` instance so that it can use this pattern:

```
def handler1(request):
    ...

def handler2(request):
    ...

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route('GET', '/one', handler1)
app.router.add_route('GET', '/two', handler2)
```

What makes my life difficult is that I have been able to bring my app instance up to the ChildProcess.**init** but **cannot figure out how to modify the start method** (I only kept the part I need help to modify):

```
class ChildProcess:

    def __init__(self, up_read, down_write, app, args, sock):
        ...
        self.app = app
        ...

    def start(self):
        ...

        # how to leverage the app.router here????
        # these few lines like aiohttp.web.run_app(app) code
        # there must be a way to make this work together
        f = loop.create_server(
            lambda: HttpRequestHandler(debug=True, keep_alive=75),
            sock=self.sock)

        srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found and I think you might be interested:

```
class ChildProcess:

    def start(self):
        ...
        # lines 123, 124, and 125 become:
        handler = web.RequestHandlerFactory(self.app, self.app.router, loop=loop,
                                            debug=True, keep_alive=75)

        f = loop.create_server(lambda: handler(), sock=self.sock)
        ...
```

The rest remains unchanged.